# requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api-fxpractice.oanda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, ssl, raspberry-pi

the script works perfectly on my MacBook however i get error whenever i try to run it on my raspberry pi. I cant seem to find a solution, can someone point me the right direction! please and thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 485, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1934, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1671, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_ske_dhe', 'dh key too small')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 491, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError("bad handshake: %r" % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_ske_dhe', 'dh key too small')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api-fxpractice.oanda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/accounts/101-004-XXXXXXXX-001/summary (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_ske_dhe', 'dh key too small')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eurusd.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bot
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/bot.py", line 14, in <module>
    import oanda
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/oanda.py", line 35, in <module>
    client.request(r)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oandapyV20/oandapyV20.py", line 306, in request
    request_args, headers=headers)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oandapyV20/oandapyV20.py", line 234, in __request
    raise err
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/oandapyV20/oandapyV20.py", line 231, in __request
    **request_args)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api-fxpractice.oanda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v3/accounts/101-XXX-XXXXXXX-001/summary (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_ske_dhe', 'dh key too small')])")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days...

Remove 'CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2' from /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=907788%20for%20more%20i